# Create dynamic div and add css Class using Asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

In my Project, When i click button create div and i need to add css class for div with curve. So i tried like this

**ASP.NET**

```
Protected Sub btnLog_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) 
Handles btnLog.Click

        DivUserDetail.Controls.Clear()

        Dim createDiv As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("DIV")
        createDiv.ID = "createDiv"
        createDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "Red")
        createDiv.InnerHtml = " I'm a div, from code behind "
        createDiv.Attributes("class") = "FirstDiv"
        DivUserDetail.Controls.Add(createDiv)

    End Sub
```

**CSS**

```
#DivUserDetail
 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    float: right;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    border-Left: 1px solid #00e5e6;
    overflow:auto;
 }
 .FirstDiv 
 {
      height: 400Px;
      width: 150px;
      position:fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      border:1px solid #4BACBC;
      -webkit-border-radius:15px;
      -moz-border-radius:15px;
 }
```

But its Show only the text. What am doing wrong here? How to Correct it?

am Using `ASP.NET 2008`

Comment: Is the text Red in color? Are you saying that the styling `.FirstDiv` is not showing?

Comment: Have you included the css in relevant page ?

Comment: in asp.Net servercode ah @MairajAhmad sir

Comment: I mean is it properly included because i ran same code and it works fine

Comment: @Sathish MairajAhmad says right. It will work properly. Just check one thing: if your page called DEFAULT (it is just example) -> your code-behind is *default.aspx.vb* and your design page is *default.aspx*. Your server code will be in *default.aspx.vb*, and your class must be in *default.aspx*. Is it correct in your project?

Comment: css class must be in default.aspx ah? sir. But i add div when click log button that time only sir... @Khazratbek

Comment: @Sathish Your page might be called in different way. I just meant that your css classes must be in design page, not in code behind.

Comment: @Sathish use the answer of PHANI -> createDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "FirstDiv") and check, that your css class in the design page. To find your errors or mistakes, you may open source code of the page and take a look on a created div: it's class, values, so on.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `class` attribute to the new HTML element.

what you are doing here is modifying the value of an existing `class` attribute, which does not exist.

Replace this:

`createDiv.Attributes("class") = "FirstDiv"`

with

`createDiv.Attributes.Add("class","FirstDiv")`

Comment: @Sathish: can you also post your aspx page HTML code......are the styles for `#DivUserDetail` showing properly on the page?....my doubt is whether your css is being loaded onto the page.